# how to implement a multi item slider in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to implement a multi item slider in angular 7.It is working fine when i'm using static data in the html but when im trying to implement the same dynamically from the angular using ngFor then in the first page it is not showing anything but when i'm sliding to next slide then it is working good fine.

this is the code with static data in html

HTML:-

```
<div class=" container-fluid news-slider">
      <div class="row mySlides fad">
            <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem">
                <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                    <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/img/download.jpg" class="newsimage">
                    <mat-card-content>
                        <div class="newsdetails">
                          The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
                          A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
                          bred for hunting.
                        </div>
                      </mat-card-content>
                </mat-card>
              </div>
              <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem">
                  <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                      <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/img/download.jpg" class="newsimage">
                      <mat-card-content>
                          <div class="newsdetails">
                            The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
                            A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
                            bred for hunting.
                          </div>
                        </mat-card-content>
                  </mat-card>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem">
                    <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                        <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/img/download.jpg" class="newsimage">
                        <mat-card-content>
                            <div class="newsdetails">
                              The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
                              A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
                              bred for hunting.
                            </div>
                          </mat-card-content>
                    </mat-card>
                  </div>
                  <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem">
                      <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                          <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/img/download.jpg" class="newsimage">
                          <mat-card-content>
                              <div class="newsdetails">
                                The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
                                A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
                                bred for hunting.
                              </div>
                            </mat-card-content>
                      </mat-card>
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem">
                        <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                            <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/img/download.jpg" class="newsimage">
                            <mat-card-content>
                                <div class="newsdetails">
                                  The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
                                  A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
                                  bred for hunting.
                                </div>
                              </mat-card-content>
                        </mat-card>
                      </div>
                      <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem">
                          <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                              <img mat-card-image src="../../assets/img/download.jpg" class="newsimage">
                              <mat-card-content>
                                  <div class="newsdetails">
                                    The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.
                                    A small, agile dog that copes very well with mountainous terrain, the Shiba Inu was originally
                                    bred for hunting.
                                  </div>
                                </mat-card-content>
                          </mat-card>
                        </div>


          </div>
        <a class="pre" (click)="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="nex" (click)="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>


CSS:-


.news-slider{
    position: relative;
}
.mySlides{
    display: none;
}
.pre,.nex{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease; 
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.nex {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  } 
  .pre{
    margin-left:-15px;
  }
   .fad {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }



Angular:-


export class MainpageComponent implements OnInit {
  slideIndex = 1;

  parent = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

   constructor(config : NgbCarouselConfig,public httpclient:HttpClient,private renderer:Renderer2) {
    config.interval = 2000;
    config.wrap = true;
    config.keyboard = false;
    config.pauseOnHover = true;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
  }

 showSlides(n)
  {
      var i;
      if(n>this.parent.length)
      {
        this.slideIndex = 1;
      }
      if(n<1)
      {
        this.slideIndex = this.parent.length;
      }
      for(i=0;i<this.parent.length;i++)
      {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.parent[i],'display','none');
      }
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.parent[this.slideIndex-1],'display','flex');
      console.log(this.parent[0]);
  }
  plusSlides(n)
  {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
  }

}
```

this is the code that i have used for dynamic display

````
HTML:-
```
<div class=" container-fluid news-slider">
      <div class="row mySlides fad" *ngFor="let newsarray of newschunk">
          <div class=" col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 newsitem" *ngFor="let item of newsarray">
              <mat-card class="insidecard newscard">
                <img mat-card-image [src]="item.img" class="newimage">
                <mat-card-content>
                    <div class="newsdetails">
                      {{item.description}}
                    </div>
                  </mat-card-content>
              </mat-card>
            </div>

          </div>
        <a class="pre" (click)="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="nex" (click)="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>


CSS:-

.news-slider{
    position: relative;
}
.mySlides{
    display: none;
}
.pre,.nex{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease; 
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.nex {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    margin-right: 0px;
  } 
  .pre{
    margin-left:-15px;
  }
   .fad {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }


ANGULAR:-

export class MainpageComponent implements OnInit {
  slideIndex = 1;

  parent = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");


  public newsdata = [
    {
      title: 'Card Title 1',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 2',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 3',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 4',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 5',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 6',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 7',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 8',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
    {
      title: 'Card Title 9',
      description: 'Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card content',
      buttonText: 'Button',
      img: 'https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/4-col/img%20(34).jpg'
    },
  ];
  public newschunk:any=[[]];

  constructor(config : NgbCarouselConfig,public httpclient:HttpClient,private renderer:Renderer2) {
    config.interval = 2000;
    config.wrap = true;
    config.keyboard = false;
    config.pauseOnHover = true;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.changecol.send("yes");

    this.getTopNews();
    //console.log(this.newsdiv);
    //console.log(this.parent[0]);   

  }


  showSlides(n)
  {
      var i;
      if(n>this.parent.length)
      {
        this.slideIndex = 1;
      }
      if(n<1)
      {
        this.slideIndex = this.parent.length;
      }
      for(i=0;i<this.parent.length;i++)
      {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.parent[i],'display','none');
      }
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.parent[this.slideIndex-1],'display','flex');
      console.log(this.parent[0]);
  }
  plusSlides(n)
  {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
  }
  getTopNews() {
    this.httpclient.get<{message:any,errorMessage:string}>("http://localhost:3000/trendingNews").subscribe((responsedata)=>{
      //this.newsdata=responsedata.message;
      this.newschunk = this.getChunks(this.newsdata,6);
      this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.newsdiv[0],'display','none');

  });
  }

  getChunks(arr,size)
  {
    let chunkarray = [];
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i+=size)
    {
      chunkarray.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
    }
    return chunkarray;
  }

}


1st image with static data in html

2nd image with dynamic data from angular without sliding

3rd image when i click the next arrow
````

**Behavior:**
[image: image 3]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 1]

Answer (score 0):

you had 2 things going on:

1. Fetch data in newschuck
2. Show the slides

**Issue #1**: You did both these tasks in ngOnInit - fetching data (point #1) is fine in OnInit, but Showing the slides (point #2) wouldn't work because ngOnInit is run before the page is rendered.

**Issue #2**: If you had put both these (point #1 & #2) in ngAfterViewInit - you get an error 'expression changed after it was checked..."

**Solution**: fetch data (point #1) in OnInit; display slides (point #2) after rendering of the page. To do this, i created a boolean variable (it'll help if in case you are getting data from a rest api).

check the [complete demo from your githib here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lppc3f)

**EDIT (1)** - to do this against a rest API, transfer the code you had inside ngAfterViewInit to the finally block `() => { }` as seen below:

```
  getTopNews() { this.httpclient.get<{ message: any, errorMessage: string }>("localhost:3000/trendingNews").subscribe(
    responsedata => { this.newsdata = responsedata.message; 
    this.newschunk = this.getChunks(this.newsdata, 3);
    this.arrayUpdated = true;
    }
    ,error => { console.log(error); this.renderer.setStyle(this.newsdiv[0], 'display', 'none'); });
    /* this is the finally block */
    () =>{     if (this.arrayUpdated) {      this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);     }}
    }
```

Comment: It is working fine when i giving static array in angular but it is working same as before when i get the array from database

Comment: yah im getting it when i give static data

Comment: getTopNews() {
    this.httpclient.get<{message:any,errorMessage:string}>("http://localhost:3000/trendingNews").subscribe((responsedata)=>{
      this.newsdata=responsedata.message;
      this.newschunk = this.getChunks(this.newsdata, 3);
      this.arrayUpdated = true;
      this.newssmall = this.newsdata.slice(0,4);
  },(error)=>{
    console.log(error);
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.newsdiv[0],'display','none');

  });
  
  }

Comment: when im doing something like this it is working same as before by not showing first page

Comment: you're experiencing this because the ngAfterViewInit fires before you had a result from the rest-api... check code changes to the code in the answer

Comment: getTopNews() {
    this.httpclient.get<{message:any,errorMessage:string}>("http://localhost:3000/trendingNews").subscribe((responsedata)=>{
      this.newsdata=responsedata.message;
      this.newschunk = this.getChunks(this.newsdata, 3);
      this.arrayUpdated = true;
      this.newssmall = this.newsdata.slice(0,4);
  },error => { 
    console.log(error); 
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.newsdiv[0], 'display', 'none'); 
  },()=>{
    if (this.arrayUpdated) 
    {      
      this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);     
    }
  });
  }

Comment: console.log(this.parent[0])

im getting this when i first load it

<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->

im getting this when i click next arrow

<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->

Comment: Im assigning parent with document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); at the beginning is  it ok?

Comment: can you make changes to this code https://github.com/suhail-1997/multisliderangular